# AT command to disconnect the dialup TAP connection

Tags: modem, at-command, dial-up

In our project, we dial a particular number, connect and then send the message successfully. After sending the message, we want to disconnect the call by sending the AT commands.

After sending the message successfully, we send #EOT#CR and then send +++ath0. It seems our dial up modem, does not disconnect call after we send +++ath0. When we see our usage on the carrier service provider website, it is showing the call duration of around up to 700 seconds. While on the debug terminal we can clearly see that the message sent successfully within less than 60 seconds.

Please give some guidance, why it does not disconnect the call.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AT Command for Hang-up(disconnect) dial-up modem is:
ATH

value:0 or 1

for example for disconnecting Send this String to Modem's port:
"ATH0;\r\n";

that semicolon determines you are able to send other AT commands.